Topological game on $(0,1)$
I consider a « game » on a topological space with $2$ players. I will describe the game and tried to prove that one of the player has no winning strategy in the sense that the other player can always « counter » his strategy.
We set $X=(0,1)$ the topological space under consideration with the induced topology.
The game is as follows

Player $A$ chooses an open set $O_1$ in $(0,1)$
Player $B$ chooses an open set $O_2$ in $O_1$
Players $A$ and $B$ cannot choose the empty set.

The game is repeated infinitely many times such that :
$\forall$ odd $n\in 2\mathbb{N}+1$ player $A$ chooses an open set $O_{n}$ in $O_{n-1}$ (with $O_0=(0,1)$) and $\forall$ even $n\in 2\mathbb{N}$ player $B$ chooses an open set $O_{n}$ in $O_{n-1}$.
Player $A$ wins if $\cap_{i\geq}O_i\neq\emptyset$ otherwise player $B$ wins.
Having thought about this game, here isa formulation on what I consider to be true and an attempt to prove it.
The player $B$ has a winning strategy that consists to take, at stage $n=2$ of the game, a point $x$ in $O_1$ and play (or chooses) for the rest of the game the open set $(x-\frac{1}{m_n}, x)$ where $m_n$ is a sequence of integers that goes to $\infty$.
Proof : Let $O_1$ be the open set chosen by player $1$, we know it is non empty. Fix $x\in O_1$, since $O_1$ is open there exists $\epsilon$ such that $N(x,\epsilon)\subset O_1$. Thus we can find a $m_1$ such that $(x-\frac{1}{m_1}, x)\subset N(x,\epsilon)\subset O_1$ and the set is open.
Now for the stage $n>2$, $n\in 2\mathbb{N}$ proceed as follow :

If $(x-\frac{1}{m_{n-1}}, x)\notin O_{n-1}$ chooses $m_n$ such that $(x-\frac{1}{m_1}, x)\subset O_{n-1}$
If $(x-\frac{1}{m_{n-1}}, x)\subset O_{n-1}$, chooses $m_{n}=m_{n-1}+1$

The sequence $m_n$ construct is increasing and tends to $\infty$, it follows that $\cap_{n\in 2\mathbb{N}} (x-\frac{1}{m_n}, x) =\emptyset$ hence the conclusion.
I would like to know if this seems to you to be a reasonable proof, and if not if you can provide some counter example I would be happy to discover this.
Thank you a lot !

Player 2's strategy may fail.
After stage 2 where player 2 chose $x \in O_1$ and $O_2 = (x-\frac{1}{m_1} x)$, perhaps player 1 inconveniently chooses $O_3 = (x - \frac{1}{m_1}, x - \frac{1}{2m_1})$.
Now it's player 2's turn, but unfortunately for him the previous choice of player 1 has put player 2's fixed choice of $x$ out of reach: there does not exist any integer $m_2$ such that
$$(x-\frac{1}{m_2},x) \subset (x - \frac{1}{m_1}, x - \frac{1}{2m_1})
$$

This strategy is not correct, due to the fact that $x$ is fixed, as explained by Lee Mosher in the other answer.
More generally it is $A$ that has a winning strategy. Indeed, if $B$ chooses $O_n$ then $A$ chooses $O_{n+1}$ in such a way that there is a compact $K_n$ between $O_n$ and $O_{n+1}$.
This can always be done, by picking small enough ball around some $x\in O_n$. "Small enough" meaning "not touching boundary of $O_n$", or more precisely: pick $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ first so that it is contained in $O_n$, and then $O_{n+1}=(x-\epsilon/2, x+\epsilon/2)$. The compact subset $K_n$ is then $[x-\delta, x+\delta]$ for some $\epsilon/2<\delta<\epsilon$.
In this situation the full intersection of all $O_n$ is equal to the intersection of all $K_n$. But it is well known that intersection of descending compact subsets is nonempty (Cantor's intersection theorem).

Thank you for the elaborated answer ! After Lee mosher answer I thought of something maybe similar to the hint you proposed by taking, for player $A$, always à open set strictement included in the previous one chosen by player $2$, we have à decreasing sequence of open set with no "fixed point" as the sequence I constructed in my post, and I am optimist about the fact that such intersection is not empty, at least I will try to prove it on $(0,1)$ !

As pointed out by Lee Mosher, the proof you give does not work. Here is how it can work.
Player A always wins. After Player B chooses an open set $O_{2k}$ for any $k = 1,2, \cdots$, choose $I_k = (a_k,b_k) \subseteq O_k$ and put $O_{2k+1} = (a_k+\epsilon_k,b_k-\epsilon_k)$. Here $\epsilon_k>0$ is chosen such that $O_{2k+1} \subseteq O_{2k}$ and $O_{2k+1}$ is an open interval.
To prove that this strategy wins, choose compact $K_n$ such that $O_{n+1} \subseteq K_n \subseteq O_n$ for $n = 1,2,\cdots$. We see that $K_{n+1} \subseteq K_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$ contains at least one point, call it $x$. We have $x \in O_n$ for every $n$ and Player A wins. This completes the proof.

You mean "Player A wins", because nonempty intersection is the winning condition for A.

Thank you. That is correct.

There is also some mess with indexes. Anyway, this is almost correct. The problem is that $I_k$ might be whole $O_{2k-1}$, and so $O_{2k}$ goes outside of $O_{2k-1}$. This can be fixed by requiring $a_k, b_k\in O_{2k-1}$ instead of $I_k\subseteq O_{2k-1}$. And then I think it is fine.

I have fixed it.

As a final note: the intersection $\cap K_n$ does not have to contain exactly one point, it can be bigger.

Yes you are right
